# Excel to PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to prepare a presentation from Excel. As of now VBA code is preparing "n number of "presentations as per no of times Loop runs. I want  Code to generate just 1 presentation with all slides combined. Fist Macro "Addnumber" is run, which run Macro "ExcelRangeToPowerPoint". Its Macro "ExcelRangeToPowerPoint"which need to add slides for every loop of Macro "Addnumber"

Please Support

```
Sub AddNumber()

Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim rngSel As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim Num As Double
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim lAreas As Long
Dim lRows As Long
Dim lCols As Long
Dim Arr() As Variant
Set rngSel = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5:A30")

Do Until Range("A30") = Range("A3")
Num = 26

For Each rng In rngSel.Areas
  If rng.Count = 1 Then
     rng = rng + Num
  Else
      lRows = rng.Rows.Count
      lCols = rng.Columns.Count
      Arr = rng
      For i = 1 To lRows
         For j = 1 To lCols
            Arr(i, j) = Arr(i, j) + Num
         Next j
      Next i
      rng.Value = Arr
  End If
Call ExcelRangeToPowerPoint

Next rng

Loop

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub ExcelRangeToPowerPoint()

'PURPOSE: Copy/Paste An Excel Range Into a New PowerPoint Presentation


Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object
Dim mySize As PageSetup
Dim Addtitle As Shape
Dim DateT As String



'Copy Range from Excel
  Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:M30")
  Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2")
  Set rng3 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3")
'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
  On Error Resume Next
'Is PowerPoint already opened?
  Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
'Clear the error between errors
  Err.Clear
'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
  If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
        Exit Sub
      End If
   On Error GoTo 0

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Create a New Presentation
  Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add
'Add a slide to the Presentation
  Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 11)
'11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly

  'Change Theme and Layout
  mySlide.ApplyTheme "C:\Users\davinder.sond\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\DefaultTheme.thmx"
  myPresentation.PageSetup.SlideSize = 3
  myPresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = rng2
  myPresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Title.Left = 59
  myPresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Title.Top = 10
  myPresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Title.Height = 30
  myPresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Title.Width = 673

  With myPresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Title

     With .TextFrame.TextRange.Font
    .Size = 24
    .Name = "Arial"
    .Bold = True
    .Color.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)

     End With

    End With

'Copy Excel Range
  rng.Copy

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
  mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
  Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

    'Set position:
      myShape.LockAspectRatio = 0

      myShape.Left = 12
      myShape.Top = 55
      myShape.Height = 475
      myShape.Width = 756

'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
  PowerPointApp.Visible = True
  PowerPointApp.Activate

DateT = Format("h:mm:ss")


'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

 myPresentation.SaveAs "C:\Project Control CCJV\ExperimentsPunch\" & rng3 & ".pptm"

PowerPointApp.Quit




End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new presentation everytime you call `Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add` within `ExcelRangeToPowerPoint()`.

You can either try to open/close the Presentation outside of `ExcelRangeToPowerPoint()` and add a parameter to the function like `ExcelRangeToPowerPoint(myPresentationObject)` then you can simple add the slides there

or

you call the function `AddNumber()` within `ExcelRangeToPowerPoint()` of coarse the you need to loop there...

e.g.

```
Sub ExcelRangeToPowerPoint()
' some preparative code
'Create a New Presentation
Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add
'Add a slide to the Presentation
 Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 11)
For Each rng in rngSel.Areas
    'Filling the presentation one slide at a time
    AddSlide(rng)
Next

'Clear The Clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False

myPresentation.SaveAs "C:\Project Control CCJV\ExperimentsPunch\" & rng3 & 
".pptm"

PowerPointApp.Quit
'some more code
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your Response !If you can help me with the code would be great. In each Loop of AddNumber(), if should check powerpoint is open or close, if open should add slides ( as per loops run ) otherwise create new presentation to add slides.

Comment: When you add the `AddNumber()`function whithin the `ExcelRangeToPowerPoint()` e.g. you already know that Powerpooint is open.

Comment: I updated my response with some pseudo code perhaps it helsp